# How to use LZF or LZO filters to compress HDF5 file in Python?

Tags: python, compression, hdf5, lzo, lzf

My hdf5 file contains three arrays: ArrayA(30,100,100),ArrayB(100,100),ArrayC(100,100),how can I use LZF or LZO filters to compress them?

Comment: Are you using [_h5py_](http://alfven.org/wp/hdf5-for-python/) or [_pytables_](http://www.pytables.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [blosc](http://blosc.pytables.org/trac) filter. It usually performs better than LZF or LZO.
This should work:

```
filters = tables.Filters(complevel=4, complib='blosc')
atom = tables.Float32Atom()
array = h5_f.createCArray(group, 'ArrayA', atom, shape, filters=filters)
array[:] = data
```